# How does pass through query increase the speed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I have heard that pass through queries increase the speed of data retrieval because T-SQL language is used at the SQL Server which is faster. However, since Jet-SQL is translated to T-SQL by the ODBC driver what advantage does pass through query posses?

Comment: Increase the speed compared to what?

Comment: Seems like you're lacking fundamental understanding about how the Access database engine works with normal queries on linked tables and passthrough queries. Such a topic is too broad for Stack Overflow. You'd better look up a good Access book. This question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: PT queries are executed using backend (sql server engine. Your case). Local queries are executed using JET engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple retrieval of records: No. As you mention, the SQL forwarded by the ODBC driver will be identical to that you would send in a PT query.

You can activate ODBC logging (look this up) and check out the SQL send to the server. Do remember to turn it off again, though.

Also, note that PT queries always are read-only.

Comment: It's far from that simple. Logic regarding query compilation, caching, connection management can differ. A quick 100 * local query `SELECT * FROM sometable` on a simple small table and 100* passthrough query showed a 5 second time difference in favor of the local query. Your answer is not correct, it's not the same.

Comment: Probably true, @ErikvonAsmuth, but querying 100 times was not what I had in mind with _simple retrieval_.

Comment: The point is, if I only query once it's not enough to be significant. I ran the same query 100 times, opening and closing every run. That means for a single query the difference is 0.05 seconds, which isn't much, but not identical nonetheless, and is about 1/5th of the total cost of the query I was running.

Comment: That's what I mean @ErikvonAsmuth - there will probably be more important tasks than optimising for 0.05s.

Comment: Yes, but still, that's not identical. The question isn't: should I change to one kind of query to optimize performance, the question is: how do passthrough queries increase speed. And that should be closed imo, because 1. they sometimes don't, 2. different versions of Access handle passthrough queries in different ways (2010 doesn't reuse connections, 2016 does in my setup, leading to a speed improvement + bugs if you use identity insert), 3. it depends on the type of query, which makes it very much too broad imo

Comment: Agree @ErikvonAsmuth, but for a single call nothing will be cached. But, it depends very much on many things. Too broad really.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS Access as a front end, and do not use a pass-thru query, Access will pull all the data it needs across the network and use it locally to run the query.  A pass-thru query does not have to go through that inefficient process of copy the data across the network.

Comment: Right, but a pt query on one table vs that of a standard linked table and a bound report or form both ONLY pull the records that meet the "where" clause (the criteria you provided). Even standard linked tables to sql server do not pull the whole table local. In the case of a standard linked table vs a pt query, you not see any performance difference here. In fact as noted above, the form with a non PT query actually might do better since it keeps the connection open.

Comment: I should also add that if you ask for data in a PT query vs that of a standard linked table, then in both cases access will only pull the records that meet the criteria - so the PT query not by magic going to run faster nor will it reduce network traffic.  That PT query only going to run faster if it involves multiple tables (joins) or updates lots of records - that can occur server side. However, pulling 10 records with a linked table or  PT query means only 10 records come down the network pipe in both cases. It is a common myth that access pulls the whole table - it does not.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I didn't think about where the filtering happened.  I didn't think about that at all.  Thanks for the elucidation.